# Creating a custom step in Oracle Data Integrator ODI using Groovy to delete duplicate rows

Tags: oracle, groovy, data-integration, oracle-data-integrator

I have a case where I need to populate a target table, I have a column "CUSTOMER_ID" which has duplicate values in various rows. I need to populate target table with only one row from CustomerID no matter which one (it can be picked randomly). Usually I use a procedure running on this query:

```
DELETE FROM Source.SALARY
      WHERE ROWID NOT IN (SELECT MAX (ROWID)
                                  FROM Source.SALARY
                              GROUP BY CUSTOMER_ID);
```

This query deletes duplicates on CUSTOMER_ID and leaves only one row.

Now I want to create a custom step on my Integration Knowledge module which uses Groovy scripting to simulate this query using ODI interface. I have already tried using code below but I'm new to Groovy and cant seem to find a solution:

```
delete from    <%=snpRef.getTable("L","TARG_NAME","A")%> 
where <%=odiRef.getColList("", "ROWID")%> not in (
select MAX(<%=odiRef.getColList("", "ROWID")%>) 
from     <%=snpRef.getTable("L","INT_NAME","A")%>
GROUP BY <%=odiRef.getColList("","[COL_NAME]","\n\tand\t","","UK")%> 
where     1=1)
```

Can someone help me fit this code to my Oracle SQL query?

Comment: Hi. ROWID exists in every target table? It's so, you can hardcode it's name. the sintax <%=odiRef.getColList("", "ROWID")%> and MAX(<%=odiRef.getColList("", "ROWID")%> are not correct. So, if you can put directly ROWID and MAX(ROWID), everything else seems to be correct!

Comment: @F.Lazarescu, No, ROWID is just a system column in Oracle used to uniquely identify each row in oracle.

Comment: ah, yeah .. I missed this. So you can write your replacing <%=odiRef.getColList("", "ROWID")%> with ROWID and MAX(<%=odiRef.getColList("", "ROWID")%>)  with MAX(ROWID).

Answer (score 1):

I did this using this code:

```
delete from    <%=snpRef.getTable("L","TARG_NAME","A")%> 
where ROWID not in (
select MAX(ROWID) 
from     <%=snpRef.getTable("L","TARG_NAME","A")%>
GROUP BY <%=odiRef.getColList("","[COL_NAME]","\n\tand\t","","UK")%>)
```

It worked perfectly fine!

Comment: I would use odiRef consistently instead of snpRef (which is there only for backwards compatibility for Sunopsis / ODI 10g).